# Rails params escape/unescape +

Tags: ruby-on-rails, escaping, uri, parameters

I want to get params of query without replacing + to " ". By default, Rails parse + like space.

```
Example /query?p=abc+abc

params[:p] = 'abc abc', not 'abc+abc'
```

How to get param without escaping?

Yes, I can do `.gsub(/[ ]/, '+')` , but how to get original params before rails unescape them?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that's possible.  The same code that converts plus to space also handles decoding `%NN` characters as well.  You can get the raw query string (for a GET request) using `request.query_string`. It will return something like this: `one=two+three&four=five+six`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Yes, i know about `request.query_string`. As i understand, i should use params parser as is, or just parse query on my own.